# Apply both Fling and ACTION_MOVE on view

Tags: android, android-view

Motion event can be easily applied by overriding `onTouch` inside `OnTouchListener`.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            paramsF.x = initialX + (int)(event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
            paramsF.y = initialY + (int)(event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
            wm.updateViewLayout(view, paramsF);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But to apply fling I have to implement the `GestureDectector`.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

How can I implement both fling and `ACTION_MOVE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GestureDectector` after `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` will make it work.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = paramsF.x;
            initialY = paramsF.y;
            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            paramsF.x = initialX + (int)(event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
            paramsF.y = initialY + (int)(event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
            mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(v, paramsF);
            break;
    }
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```